# Send XML document in the HTTP body

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API controller with method

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
  try
  {
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("test.xml");

    return Ok(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return InternalServerError(ex);
  }
}
```

The XML document show as string in the HTTP message body

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><TestInfo xmlns=\"http://myschema\"><ID>171961</CSOSAID>...</TestInfo>"
```

I want it to be in simple XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TestInfo xmlns="http://myschema"><ID>171961</ID>...</TestInfo>
```

How could I do it? Try several ways but couldn't get? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see the body? In the debugger? It's unlikely to contain `\"` in the real body. Try using "View Source" to make sure what it looks like.

Comment: I am using Fiddler to test and I can see the raw message.

Comment: I suggest you look at the source of the page after the XML is returned. `\"` and having quotes around it is a strange way to create XML.

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing the String object using an XMLSerializer which is not what you want.

You can do this,

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
  try
  {
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("test.xml");

    return new ResponseMessageResult(new HttpResponseMessage() {Content = new StringContent(xmlDoc.InnerXml, Encoding.UTF8,"application/xml")});
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return InternalServerError(ex);
  }
}
```

or you can create your own IHttpActionResult helper class, like this,

```
public class XmlResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly XmlDocument _doc;

        public XmlResult(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            _doc = doc;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return
                Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(_doc.InnerXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
                });
        }
    }
```

which would then allow you to do,

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
      try
      {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml("test.xml");

        return new XmlResult(xmlDoc);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
      }
    }
```

or you could switch to XElement which will magically do the right thing,

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
          try
          {
            XElement xElement = XElement.Load(..);

            return OK(xElement);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
          }
        }
```

You can find more details on why the behaviour is the way it isin this blog post http://www.bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api

Comment: I used your first suggestion and it works as I want. Thank you very much.